# LocationRectangle Width and Height

Tags: windows-phone-8

Does anyone know what value the width and height are specified for the constructor?

```
LocationRectangle Constructor (GeoCoordinate, Double, Double)
```

Are they the width and height of the actual map control on the XAML page, or are they the width and height in degrees latitude or longitude?  Or some other measurement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj208128(v=vs.105).aspx) documentation doesn't specify what is it, but as small test showed:

[image: Widt and height]

those values are in Degrees.